# Reference \part in chapter page?

Tags: cross-referencing, chapters, parts

i'm looking for a way to show in each Chapter page, as well the part or section it belongs to.
In my document, i've created VI parts, part I, II, III, ... , VI and different chapters belong to different part.
How could I show part IV as an example on the first page of Chapter 6?

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt, a4paper, footinclude=true, headinclude=true, cleardoublepage=empty]{scrbook}
    \usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{acronym}
    \usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={2.8cm, 2.8cm}, vmargin={2.5cm, 2.5cm}]{geometry}
    \usepackage{eso-pic} % \AddToShipoutPicture
    \usepackage{graphicx} % \includegraphics
    \graphicspath{
        {Pics/PDFs/}
        {Pics/JPGs/}
        {Pics/PNGs/}
    }
    \usepackage{color, colortbl}
    \definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
    \definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
    %\usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{footnote}
    \usepackage{verse}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{cmap}
    \usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage{bookmark}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{times}
    \usepackage{lingmacros}
    \usepackage{color, colortbl}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{footnote}
    \definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.86,0.86,0.86}
    \makesavenoteenv{tabular}
    \makesavenoteenv{table}
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0}
    \def\signed #1{{\leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip2em
      \hbox{}\nobreak\hfil(#1)%
        \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \endgraf}}
    
        \newsavebox\mybox
        \newenvironment{aquote}[1]
          {\savebox\mybox{#1}\begin{quote}}
              {\signed{\usebox\mybox}\end{quote}}
    
    
    \renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{} % get rid of "table"
    \renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{}
    
    \newcolumntype{S}{>{\footnotesize}l} % define a new column type for \small
    
    \usepackage{mdframed}
    
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{threeparttable}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \newcommand{\tabhead}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
    \newcommand{\rothead}[1]{\rotatebox{45}{\tabhead{#1}}}
    
    \usepackage{tipa}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \usepackage{breqn}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    %\doublespacing
    % or:
    \onehalfspacing
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    
    
    %for R code
    \usepackage{listings}
    \lstset{    language=R,                       
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, numbers=left,
    stepnumber=5,                    
    numbersep=5pt, backgroundcolor=\color{white}, frame=single,   
    captionpos=b,                        keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    breaklines=true,
      postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space}}
    
    
    %Box around fig
    \usepackage{wrapfig, framed, caption}
    
    
    
    %\usepackage[backend=biber,style=nature,dashed=false,sorting=nty, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
    
    \usepackage[%
      backend=bibtex      % biber or bibtex
    ,style=authoryear    % Alphabeticalsch
    %,style=numeric-comp  % numerical-compressed
     ,sorting=nyt        % no sorting
     ,sortcites=true      % some other example options ...
     ,bibencoding=ascii
     ,block=none
     ,indexing=false
     ,citereset=none
     ,isbn=true
     ,url=true
     ,doi=true            % prints doi
     ,natbib=true         % if you need natbib functions
    ]{biblatex}
    
    \addbibresource{references.bib} %Imports bibliography file
    
    \def \ColourPDF {Images/ku-farve.pdf}
    \def \TitlePDF   {Images/ku-en.pdf}
    
    
    \subject{ 
      \vspace{2.5cm}
     % \scriptsize{A thesis presented to the Faculty of Science in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree} \\
      \Large{Master of Science in } \\}
    
    \title{
    \vspace{1.0cm}
    \Large{Title}
      \vspace{0.5cm} \\}
    
    \author{
      \Large\textbf{Name Surname} \\
      \texttt{email address}
      \vspace{4.5cm} \\
      \large{Supervisors: }\\
    \textbf{Name surname}\\
    \large{Co-supervisors: }\\
    {\textbf{Name surname}\\\vspace{.01in}}
    \textbf{Name surname}\\
    \vspace{1cm} \\}
    \date{October 20th, 2020}
    
    
    
    \begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,0){\includegraphics*[viewport=0 0 700 600]{\ColourPDF}}}
    \AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,602){\includegraphics*[viewport=0 600 700 1600]{\ColourPDF}}}
    \AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,0){\includegraphics*{\TitlePDF}}}
    \clearpage\maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \include{FrontBackMatter/dedication}
    
    \include{FrontBackMatter/acknowledgements}
    
    \include{FrontBackMatter/abstract}
    
    \include{FrontBackMatter/contents}
    
    \include{FrontBackMatter/abbreviations}
    
    %\include{FrontBackMatter/symbols}
    
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    
    
    
    \part{Project description}\label{Part:I}
    \include{Projectdescription/Introduction}
    \include{Projectdescription/Background}
    
    
    \part{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase Da}ata validation and 
    \texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase Li}ifetime Correction method}\label{Part:II}
    \include{Datav_lifetime/Datavalidation} \label{chap:Datavalidation}
    \include{Datav_lifetime/Methodology} \label{chap:Methodology} 
    \include{Datav_lifetime/Results0} \label{chap:Results0}
    
    \part{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase Pr}reliminary analysis}\label{part:III}
    \include{PreliminaryAnalysis/Methodology1} \label{chap:Methodology1}
    \include{PreliminaryAnalysis/CA} \label{chap:Results0} 
    \include{PreliminaryAnalysis/PCA} \label{chap:Results2}
     
    
    \part{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase Ap}ppendices} \label{part:VI}
    \include{Appendices/AppendixA} \label{chap:appendixA}
    \include{Appendices/AppendixB} \label{chap:appendixB}
    
    
    
    \medskip
    
    \printbibliography[
    heading=bibintoc,
    title={Bibliography}
    ] 
    
     
    \clearpage
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your objective(s). E.g., *where* on the chapter header page should the part number be shown? As part of the (composite) page number? As part of the chapter number? As something else? Please be specific.

Comment: You label the parts so on the first page of a chapter you can write "This chapter is in Part \ref{part-label}", perhaps putting it as a marginal note.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE.  It would help if you would remove the unnecessary stuff from your example.  Most of those packages have nothing to do with parts, chapters, and labeling.

Comment: @Mico hi, i was thinking in the top right corner. I do not look for a simple \ref but more to show the text "Part IV - Name " in the top right corner or where it would look nice just to clarify that chapter X belongs to that part. It is clear in the list of content but while you read the document, it gets easily forgotten after a couple of chapters.

Comment: This is the same document you used in your last question, please post documents in a form that people can run to see your problem and text answers. No one can use the code you have posted above as it includes files that we do not have. Make a small one-file example. Also please fix your preamble, why specify color, colortbl,tabularx twice?? For the example you should just include packages used in the example, otherwise it makes it much harder for anyone to trace the code and help.